# Core Data entity inheritance. Return entity subclass based on attribute value

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Let's assume we have ***ServiceProvider*** entity with attribute *identifier*.
And then i create **ConcreteServiceProvider** entity which is inherited from **ServiceProvider**. 
What should i do to make Core Data return list of **ServiceProvider** objects, except for ServiceProvider with identifier == 5 it should be **ConcreteServiceProvider**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly! The right answer is to prefill Core Data with desired entities.

Answer (score 0):

**you can fetch only one kind of entity in each request.**

so  i would execute a NSFetchRequest of the ConcreteServiceProvider entity and set it's predicate to fetch only those with identifier == 5. then i would execute another NSFetchRequest but this time i'll ask for all the ServiceProvider entities. having the result array of serviceProvider instances i would iterate over them and replace the ones that have identifier == 5 with the ConcreteServiceProvider instances.. (assuming those where actually ConcreteServiceProvider, you might need to introduce a helper attribute to distinguish, you can't avoid it since you can only fetch for one kind of entity at a time..).

Comment: This isn't true, you can fetch sub-entities as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/includesSubentities